# Android Volley call takes almost 8 mins to get a response

Tags: android, android-volley

I am calling one API in android and my server is on Azure.

Volley almost taking 8 mins to get a response. I am not getting any time our error. I also tried this, while parsing object I tried to passing null but the result is same. I tried the same API on my machine from POSTMAN it response immediately(1148 ms).

This is my API Call:

```
Log.e("API","STARTED");
final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
GenericRequest<SearchDto> searchRequest = new GenericRequest<SearchDto>
        (Request.Method.GET, APIUrls.get().Search(searchStr),
                SearchDto.class, null,
                new Response.Listener<SearchDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(SearchDto searchDto) {
                        System.out.println();
                       Log.e("Time",System.currentTimeMillis() - t1 +"");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        String res = AppUtils.getVolleyError(MainActivity.this, error);
                        AppUtils.openSnackBar(drawer_layout, res);
                    }
                });

ApiService.get().addToRequestQueue(searchRequest);
```

This is how I am parsing volley network response:

```
@Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        // The magic of the mute request happens here
        if (muteRequest) {
            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
                // If the status is correct, we return a success but with a null object, because the server didn't return anything
                return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        } else {
            try {
                // If it's not muted; we just need to create our POJO from the returned JSON and handle correctly the errors
                String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                T parsedObject = gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
                return Response.success(parsedObject, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }catch (Exception e){
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you already tried to inspect the call using Network Profiler? It could help to identify any possible issues in your network communication. Also, can you provide some code?

Comment: Without code no one can help you

Comment: post your `code`

Comment: I have modified the question please have a look. I have added code and let me know if you need more code snippet from me.

Comment: @GregorioPalamà no, I haven't tried. I will try and let you know.